# Flash CS6 AS3, Resetting Sound Channel

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, audio, reset, channel

I've had a problem for a while trying to reset an audio loop to the beginning when loaded into Actionscript with this code i got from the official help forum

```
var alreadyExecuted:Boolean;
if(!alreadyExecuted){
alreadyExecuted=true;

var s:Sound=new SkaianSpirit();
var sc:SoundChannel=s.play(0,1);
}
```

What i want it to do, is loop indefinitely while the animation is playing regardless of positioning and whether or not frames have been skipped with buttons etc, but when the end of the animation comes, the track needs to end. At which point, if a button is clicked to send it back to the beginning of the animation, i want it to start the same loop as before.
Currently, it will do the first part, but will not replay.

A couple caveats:

I am not loading it through a url.

I am not using buttons to control audio volume etc. It is to play automatically when the animation starts.

I am a complete and utter novice with Actionscript. I will not know what you're talking about if you lambast me with jargon i won't understand.

I'd highly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm always use `addFrameScript` function for synchronizing external sounds with animations:

UPD: mc is the name of your animation. Place this code in the place (the first frame of the parent Sprite that holds the animation for instance) where your animation is created.

```
var s:Sound=new SkaianSpirit();
var sc:SoundChannel;

mc.addFrameScript(1, startSound); 
mc.addFrameScript(mc.totalFrames - 1, stopSound);

function startSound():void
{
    sc = s.play();
}
function stopSound():void
{
    sc.stop();
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more detailed?

Comment: this code starts sound when animation mc stars (calls function startSound when animation is at first frame, place your code that start sound into this function) and stop sound when animation ends (calls stopSound when animation is at the last frame, don't forget to write code that actually stops sound into this function).

Comment: Like i said i don't actually know what any of the code would be. Could you layout the code in the proper manner, please?

Comment: It may be that because of a miscommunication my part, since when i referred to an animation, i meant the entirety of the swf not just a movie clip for example. But the code doesn't work without an mc, and since none exists, i removed the mc. call from the code. The problem now is that it can start the sound, and loop it, but it doesn't stop it, and when the replay button is pressed it just layers the sound. There was a click to stop sound snippet attached to it previously, but your code clashed with it and made the whole timeline loop without stopping on the last frame as intended.